# NPSP - Can you use data loader to update Spouse?

Tags: data-loader, relationships, npsp

Is it possible to update existing contacts in a household to create relationships?  There are too many steps (in my opinion) create a relationship between two members of a household.

Thank you!

Comment: question is not clear. What are steps you are thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. You create a CSV file to import into the relationships object. Here's what the header and some sample data would look like:

```
NPE4__CONTACT__C,NPE4__RELATEDCONTACT__C,NPE4__TYPE__C
99999999999aaaa,99999999999aaab,Husband
99999999999aaab,99999999999aaaa,Wife
```

Where 9999.... are the ids of the contacts.